# Is there a unicode dash without padding?

Tags: unicode, fonts

Here is a list of unicode dash characters: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd

Are any of these specified to have zero padding -- as in if I were to have two of them consecutively, a "correct" font rendering would make it look like one unbroken line?

Comment: Should you use n-dash or m-dash? Or you mean the part on engineering drawing? (which should have your expected behaviour (my interpretation), but many (all?) fonts doesn't respect it. (or box drawing, e.g. for 8-bit simulators, which seems to have better support: PacMan is more important then drawing a bridge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than dash or hyphens, I'd look at the box drawing components, e.g U+2500 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL (─):

──────────────────────────────────────

But results may vary depending on the font.